# How to fix ubuntu calculator & System monitor garbled-character problem?

Tags: gedit, system-monitor, gnome-calculator, character-set

System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, x86_64

Garbled-character problem as shown in the image below:

[image: Calculator Problem]

[image: System Monitor Problem]

But the gedit (Default Text Monitor) works fine:

[image: Gedit Works Fine]

How could I fix this?

Comment: suggestion : those apps are snaps packages, try to uninstall those snaps and install apps from std repos with apt. `sudo snap remove gnome-characters gnome-logs gnome-calculator gnome-system-monitor && sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get -y install gnome-characters gnome-logs gnome-calculator gnome-system-monitor`

Comment: wow, it works, thank you very much!

Comment: @cmak.fr That makes for an answer, do you mind adding it?

Comment: answer now added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suggestion : those apps are snaps packages, try to uninstall those snaps and install apps from std repos with apt.

```
sudo snap remove gnome-characters gnome-logs gnome-calculator gnome-system-monitor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install gnome-characters gnome-logs gnome-calculator gnome-system-monitor
```